# running web project on physical android browser having different internet connection

Tags: android

When I run my 'web project' in the browser of physical Android device , it runs successfully because both have the same internet conneciton.

What if my phone and my PC both having different internet connection. I still want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referencing to a local IP that is only valid / visible / accessible on your network. To open this IP to others you might use a service like DynDNS or share data over a server where both peers know only the server they communicate with.